# Ebean not persisting foreign keys

Tags: scala, playframework, ebean

I have a simple Entity class like;

```
case class Place(var name: String) extends Model with GeoLocPoint with HasGeoLoc with ContainsTime with HasId {

  var number: String = _ // Building number on the street.
  var placeGroupId: Long = _
  var chainId: Long = _
  @OneToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "logo_id")
  var logo: Image = _
  @OneToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "cover_id")
  var cover: Image = _
...
}
```

And the image class is;

```
package models.images

import javax.persistence.Entity

import models.HasId
import models.places.placegroups.places.{Place, LinkedToPlace}
import play.api.libs.json._
import play.db.ebean.Model
import play.db.ebean.Model.Finder

/**
 * Created by asheshambasta on 31/12/14.
 */
@Entity
case class Image(
                  filePath: String,
                  src: String,
                  format: String,
                  role: String // C: cover, L: logo, G: gallery
                  ) extends Model with HasId with LinkedToPlace {
  var caption: String = _
}
```

Now when a place is created, I'm attaching a default image to it;

```
  newPlace.save
  val imgDir = Play.current.configuration.getString("static.dir").getOrElse("/tmp")
  val imgUrl = Play.current.configuration.getString("static.url.img").getOrElse("/static/img")
  val imgType = Play.current.configuration.getString("img.default.type").getOrElse("image/jpeg")
  val coverFile = Play.current.configuration.getString("img.default.cover.file").getOrElse("default-cover.jpg")
  val logoFile = Play.current.configuration.getString("img.default.cover.file").getOrElse("default-cover.jpg")
  val cover = new Image(imgDir + "/" + coverFile, imgUrl + "/" + coverFile, imgType, "C")
  cover.place = newPlace
  cover.save
  val logo = new Image(imgDir + "/" + logoFile, imgUrl + "/" + logoFile, imgType, "L")
  logo.place = newPlace
  logo.save
  newPlace.cover = cover
  newPlace.logo = logo
  newPlace.update
```

But then every time, I see that the images get persisted correctly with the right place_id but the place logo and the cover don't. They stay null.

This seems straight forward, and yet it doesn't work. Does anyone have any pointers to why?

Comment: Was my answer helpful? I havn't received any feedback from you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some innacuracies in provided code. There is

```
logo.place = newPlace
```

but there is no `place` field in `Image` class.

There is also `place_id` column mentioned but I cannot see it in the code. But there are `logo_id` and `cover_id` columns. When you do one-to-one relation you should add join-column only on one side of this relation. So it should be only `logo_id` and `cover_id` columns on `Place` table. Adding only `place_id` column on `Image` table would not work because there would be two rows in `Image` table with the same `place_id` and this would be impossible to distinguish which should be mapped to `logo` field and which to `cover` field.

I made some corrections and simplifications to make this code compile and work.

Place.scala:

```
@Entity
class Place( var aId: Int, var aNumber: String) extends Model{

    @Id
    val id:Int=aId

    @Column(name="number")  
    var number: String = aNumber

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn (name = "logo_id") 
    var logo: Image = _

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "cover_id")
    var cover: Image = _
}
```

Image.class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "image")
class Image(var aId: Int, var aCaption: String) extends Model {

    @Id
    val id:Int=aId

    @Column(name="caption")
    var caption: String = aCaption
}
```

test method:

```
"EbeanTest" should {
    "placeTest" in new WithApplication {

        val newPlace = new Place(1, "aaa")
        newPlace.save

        val logo: Image  = new Image(1, "111");
        logo.save

        val cover: Image  = new Image(2, "222");
        cover.save

        newPlace.logo=logo
        newPlace.cover=cover
        newPlace.update


        val cList = Ebean.find(classOf[Place]).findList()
        for (
            element <- cList
        ) println(element.id+" "+element.number+" "+element.logo.id+" "+element.cover.id)           
    }
}
```